# How to execute an external command asynchronously in gVim 8.1 without starting a new cmd every time and append the output to an existing buffer

Tags: windows, vim

I want to execute a batch file and display the output on a new buffer. I know I can use `!start` for this, but I can't figure out how to make it reuse the same command-line instead of starting a new one every time.

I managed to get close by using `:terminal` instead with `send_keys()`, checking if the terminal buffer still exists and only starting a new one when it doesn't. The problem with this is that what I get is an interactive shell, so I have to switch to Terminal-Normal mode to be able to navigate the contents of the buffer otherwise cmd steals focus from vim and doesn't let me move around. Also the prompt itself is part of the output, which is annoying.

Here's the code:

```
fun! MatchAnyInList(list, value)
    return index(map(a:list, 'v:val =~# "' . a:value . '"'), 1) >= 0
endfun

" I have no idea what I'm doing    
fun! RunBuildBatchFile()
    if !exists("g:terminal_bufnum") || MatchAnyInList(['finished', ''], term_getstatus(g:terminal_bufnum))
        let g:terminal_bufnum = term_start("cmd", {'hidden': 1})
        call term_sendkeys(g:terminal_bufnum, "vcvarsall x64\<CR>")
    endif

    if bufwinnr(g:terminal_bufnum) < 0
        execute "botright sb " . g:terminal_bufnum
        call term_setsize(g:terminal_bufnum, 4, 0)
    endif

    call term_sendkeys(g:terminal_bufnum, "cls\<CR>")
    call term_sendkeys(g:terminal_bufnum, "C:\\Path\To\Executable\Command.exe")

    if term_getstatus(g:terminal_bufnum)=~# "normal"
        call feedkeys("i")
    endif
endfun
```

There's probably a much better way of doing this. I tried looking for information about this stuff online and in the docs but I didn't get anywhere.  Any ideas?

Comment: What's so bad about starting a new `cmd.exe` for each run? As this runs asynchronously, anyway, this doesn't block Vim at all. (Also, on Unix, shells are spawned all the time.)

Comment: @IngoKarkat I need to run other things to set variables that will be used by the command. Since these take time to run, I only want to execute these things once and run commands on the same cmd afterwards.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, you could (once) generate a batch file that contains those variable definitions (or alternatively read them into Vim), and then `call vars.bat` at the beginning of each asynchronous invocation.